DNS for IOT device, in semmi-closed networks
I have a device, that has a dedicated Ethernet port for support/monitoring/troubleshooting etc. It works by the user connectes a laptop by Ethernet, where the device provides an IP and DNS server, by DHCP.
Instead of instructing the user to open http://10... it is preferable to have a DNS entry, such as myproduct.sometld.
Since the users latop could be on the internet, it is not deterministic if online servers are used or the DNS provided by DHCP.
Original idea was to buy the domain "myproduct.sometld" and create an A record for 10.... - that means the lookup would result in the same resolved address independet of the what nameservers are used (online or local).
Next issue is DNSSEC, the bind9 on the device is not DNSSEC enabled and creates issues with browsers requiring secure DNS.
Is there any way to reuse/dublicate the online signed entry? Could I generate local keys on the device and sign the local zone my self, without any issues?

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/hosts.5.html ? (Assuming you have Linux on the laptop; Windows has something similar too, I think.)

Not a bad idea, but I cant control the users laptop, unfortunately.
